# How would one change the class of a rendered list item depending on its index with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following Vue.js template code:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="{col-sm-4: index !== 0, col-sm-8: index === 0}" >
    <a :title="item.title" :href="item.link">
        <img :title="item.title" :src="item.image" :alt="item.alt" class="img img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like the first item in the list to be rendered with the "col-sm-8" class and the subsequent items to use the "col-sm-4" class. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a ternary statement for this, like so:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="[(index === 0) ? 'col-sm-8' : 'col-sm-4]" >
    <a :title="item.title" :href="item.link">
        <img :title="item.title" :src="item.image" :alt="item.alt" class="img img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's an example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15Lgrj92/

You may also use an array of objects if you need to apply more conditions:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="[{'col-sm-8': index === 0}, {'col-sm-4': index !== 0}]" >
    <a :title="item.title" :href="item.link">
        <img :title="item.title" :src="item.image" :alt="item.alt" class="img img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's the JSfiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/opa5aq98/

You can find more info in ths docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realised that putting the class name as a string was what made the difference. Both ways of doing it now work, but I think i prefer your way using the ternary statement.